# How to update database within RxJava Observable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, observable

I am running a program in Android/Java to simulate a sports team season, as such I have Team objects.  I have a Model class which I use to communicate with my database via a ContentResolver/ContentProvider.

I am using RxJava to communicate with my database on the Schedulers.io thread so that I don't clog up the Main Thread.

In my "InsertTeam" method, I am able to insert into the database just fine.  However, in my "UpdateTeam" method, the observable/subscription isn't being run and my database is not getting updated  (i.e. the method is called but the observable does not run - nothing happens).
However, if I run my UpdateTeam observable on the AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), then it works (but slows my program)!

This does not make any sense to me.  Does anyone have insight as to why my update observable would work on the MainThread but not on the Schedulers.io thread?

**InsertTeamMethod**

```
 @Override
public void insertTeam(final Team team) {

    //Insert a team into the database

    Observable<Uri> insertTeamObservable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public Uri call() throws Exception {
            String name = team.getName();
            double elo = team.getELO();
            double offRating = team.getOffRating();
            double defRating = team.getDefRating();
            int currentWins = team.getWins();
            int currentLosses = team.getLosses();
            int currentDraws = team.getDraws();
            int division = team.getDivision();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_NAME, name);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_ELO, elo);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_OFF_RATING, offRating);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_DEF_RATING, defRating);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_WINS, currentWins);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_LOSSES, currentLosses);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_DRAWS, currentDraws);
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_DIVISION, division);

            //Insert values into database
            Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(TeamEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
            return uri;
        }
    });

    insertTeamObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            mCompositeDisposable.add(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Uri uri) {
            team.setUri(uri);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });


}
```

**UpdateTeamMethod**

```
@Override
public void updateTeam(final Team team) {

    //Update a team in the database

    Log.d("Before team obs",  "" + team.getName());

    Observable<Integer> updateTeamObservable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            //Update team database wins, losses and win loss pct values
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_WINS, team.getWins());
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_LOSSES, team.getLosses());
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_CURRENT_DRAWS, team.getDraws());
            values.put(TeamEntry.COLUMN_TEAM_WIN_LOSS_PCT, team.getWinLossPct());

            int rowsUpdated = contentResolver.update(team.getUri(), values, null, null);

            Log.d("Team updated:  ", "" + team.getName());

            return rowsUpdated;
        }
    });

    updateTeamObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            mCompositeDisposable.add(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer rowsUpdated) {
            Log.d("Team rows updated: ", " " + rowsUpdated);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: It's probably throwing an error. Try adding a log statement in your `onError`.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed throwing an error "java.lang.NullPointerException: uri".
The teams I update won't have a Uri until they are inserted into the DB.  I think my program is trying to call the insert/update methods simultaneously so sometimes the Uris are null.  I'll need to restructure my method calls.

Comment: The way I fixed this is by using an Observable.fromIterable() in my insert method.  I don't call the updateTeam method in my code until the Observer onComplete method has been called in the Observable.